# Best practises for server events with ApolloGraphql

Tags: apollo-server, server-sent-events, graphql-subscriptions

My team and I are running a Apolloserver for our app and we have a feature request that requires us to use subscriptions or SSE. In short we need to intercept orders from multiple clients and send them as print requests to a client that is connected to the printer.

I've got something to work with Apollo 2 and the included PubSub class, but with Apollo 3 I haven't yet been able to create a working solution. I've been down the rabbit hole with Apollo 2 vs Apollo 3 and apollo-server-express with subscription-transport-ws or graphql-ws, but it just feels like I'm pulling random levers.
I'm also pretty new to subscriptions as well, so that doesn't exactly help my case.

Is there some "best practices" for setting up subscriptions / sse with Apollo?

Can I use the query and mutation part of my api over HTTP (as normal), even if I have implemented subscriptions?

Is there a way to make the Apollo playground work with subscriptions or sse?

Any insight is appreciated!